# Why people say mmap by MappedByteBuffer is faster?

Tags: java, mmap

I think mmap is not fast as using virtual memory, it still has harddisk I/O.

But many people on Internet say it's fast, but no reason.

In my test, I read a file using BufferedReader andMappedByteBuffer, the first one is faster.

Comment: It really depends upon the operations being done. If reading sequentially through a file, then *please use a simple BufferedReader*. MappedByteBuffer/mmap is for more advanced use-cases (and those outside of even what RandomAccessFile can offer) that generally depend upon the physical structure in a very specific way.

Comment: Could you say about something of the advanced use-cases or any URLs? :)

Comment: Part of the premise is incorrect. mmap *is* virtual memory; at the system level they're the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

A `MappedByteBuffer` is suitable for reading binary files that are not read sequentially.

An example is reading a database index file containing
tree data-structures with file offsets to other parts of the file.  In this
case, you are continually seeking forwards and backwards in the file and
reading data and
my tests showed that using a `MappedByteBuffer` was much faster than using a 
`RandomAccessFile`.

Reading a text file or binary file sequentially with a `BufferedReader`
or `BufferedInputStream` is efficient.  There is normally no advantage in using
a memory mapped file for this and the overhead of managing the memory mapping
will probably make a `MappedByteBuffer` slower than a `BufferedReader` or `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: What "overhead of managing the memory mapping?" MappedByteBuffer should translate directly into mmap(), which is cheap. I think the overhead you're seeing is the overhead of moving data from a ByteBuffer into any of the standard Java types; that's slow.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that a read-only mapped file has nearly no impact on your heap size, because it's discardable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason mmap is faster is the file is not all read into memory at once. The file is mapped against an address in memory, and you can access it in a non sequential way without loading the parts of the file you don't need to process.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap

This is sort of application specific, but it's really meant for large files that are only partially processed and files that wouldn't normally fit into memory. There are other use cases such as shared memory and shared objects. Dynamically linked libraries are loaded using mmap so that they do not need to be loaded from the disk for every process that wants to use them. The second process to use a shared library is actually looking at the same physical memory as the first process.